# delete elements from a matrix and calculate mean

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have an N-by-M-Matrix as input called GR which consists of the following numbers: -3,0,2,4,7,10,12
And I have to return a vector. If M=1, then it should just return the input.

If M>1 It should remove the lowest number from the matrix and then calculate the mean of the remaining numbers.
However, if one of the numbers in the row is -3, it should return the value -3 in the output.

My thoughts of the problem:

Is it possible to make a for loop?

```
for i=1:length(GR(:,1))
If length(GR(1,:))==1
GR=GR
end
If length(GR(1,:))>1
x=min(GR(i,:))=[] % for removing the lowest number in the row
 GR=sum(x)/length(x(i,:))
```

I just don't have any Idea of how to detect if any of the numbers in the row is -3 and then return that value instead of calculating the mean and when I tried to delete the lowest number in the matrix using x=min(GR(i,:)) MATLAB gave me this error massage:

> 'Deletion requires an existing variable.'

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Nan`'s, `nanmean`, `any`, and `dim` argument in these functions:

```
% generate random matrix
M = randi(3);
N = randi(3);
nums = [-3,0,2,4,7,10,12];
GR = reshape(randsample(nums,N*M,true),[N M]);
% computation:
% find if GR has only one column
if size(GR,2) == 1
    res = GR;
else
    % find indexes of rows with -3 in them
    idxs3 = any(GR == -3,2); 
    % the (column) index of the min. value in each row
    [~,minCol] = min(GR,[],2); 
    % convert [row,col] index pair into linear index
    minInd = sub2ind(size(GR),1:size(GR,1),minCol');
    % set minimum value in each row to nan - to ignore it on averaging
    GR(minInd) = nan;
    % averaging each rows (except for the Nans)
    res = nanmean(GR,2);
    % set each row with (-3) in it to (-3)
    res(idxs3) = -3;
end
disp(res)
```

Comment: Can you maybe explain some of the code I have used matlab's help commando but I'm not quite sure what idxs3, minCol and minInd does

Comment: i added comments explaining each line. tell me if it's still not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I put in a break function. As soon as it detects a -3 value it breaks from the loop. Same goes for the other function.

Note that it is an i,j (M*N) matrix. So you might need to change your loop.

```
for i=1:length(GR(:,1))

if GR(i,1)==-3
GR=-3
break
end

If length(GR(1,:))==1

GR=GR
break
end

If length(GR(1,:))>1
x=min(GR(i,:))=[] % for removing the lowest number in the row
 GR=sum(x)/length(x(i,:))
end

end
```

Comment: You first need to define your hierarchy of decisions clearly. Make a list of priorities and than it will be easy to write the loop.